# Tratamento de retorno do AJAX com JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte script, que processa o form e atualiza a div #lista por ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cdb = $("#cdb").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "confere.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {cdb: cdb}
            }).done(function(data){
                $("#cdb").val("");
                $("#cdb").focus();
                listar();
            }).fail(function(data){
                alert("Erro");
            });
        });
    });
    function listar() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"lista.php",
            success: function (textStatus) {      
                $('#lista').html(textStatus);
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

O que eu gostaria era tratar o retorno do `confere.php`, e não só validar com o `.done` e `.fail`.

Por exemplo:
O retorno do `confere.php` poderá ser "X", "Y", "Z", e conforme o retorno, executar uma ação.

Arquivo: `confere.php`

```
<?php

$cdb = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'cdb');
$valor = $cdb/10;

gravar($valor);

function gravar($texto){
    $arquivo = "temp.txt";
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
    fwrite($fp, $texto . ";");
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

Comment: Você sabe o que é o parâmetro `data` que você utilizou no `.done`?

Comment: Puts não, e não tinha reparado. Conheço quase nada de JQUERY. Se tiver algum artigo bom sobre essas requisições, agradeço demais !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer o retorno da página `PHP` em `JSON`:

Quando der certo, você retorna verdadeiro:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  "result" => true
));
```

Quando não, você retorna falso:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  "result" => false
));
```

Você também pode retornar outros valores junto, por exemplo, quando der erro retornar a mensagem de erro:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  "result" => false,
  "message" => "Erro x"
));
```

Para tratar essa resposta faz da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formulario").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var cdb = $("#cdb").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "confere.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {cdb: cdb}
        }).done(function(data){
            if (data.result){
                $("#cdb").val("");
                $("#cdb").focus();
               listar();
            } else{
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }).fail(function(data){
            alert("Erro");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Se usar o `dataType: 'json'` você não precisa do `JSON.parse`

Comment: O retorno "padrão" é em JSON então ? Se eu alterar  para `dataType: 'json'` continuará funcionando o que eu estou passando pelo `POST`?

Comment: Sim, continuara, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: Alterei, obrigado pela observação @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Se eu coloco `dataType: "json"` já me dá falha na solicitação. Se eu deixo `dataType: "html"` e o retorno `alert(data.message)` aparece `undefined`.

Comment: O que a sua página `PHP` esta retornando?

Comment: Opa ! acabei de achar o motivo. Estava vindo um "0". Coloquei `dataType: "json"` e agora foi ! Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

Como você não colocou um exemplo do seu retorno vou assumir não faz dessa forma. Uma das formas de fazer isso é retornando um JSON no seguinte formato:

```
{
    "retorno": "x",
    "dados":"seus dados vão aqui",
    "erro":true,
    "msg-erro":"usuário não autorizado a fazer operação"
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu tenho 4 dados retornando do meu script. Um `retorno` que me diz qual tipo de operação eu vou fazer no meu fronto, `dados` que pode conter todos os dados retornados (inclusive pode ter um JSON dentro de outro), `erro` que me informa se ouve algum erro na aplicação e `msg-erro` que contem a mensagem de erro, caso exista.

Nesse modelo você poderia fazer o seguinte pra testar seu retorno.

```
.done(function(data){
    if(data.retorno == "x"){
        alert('retorno do tipo X');
    }else if(data.retorno == "Y"){
        alert('retorno do tipo Y');
    }
}
```

Esse foi só um exemplo do tipo de retorno, mas você pode montar sua própria estrutura. Eu gosto desse modelo pois já testo a variável de erro de cara, e se ela form true já exibo a mensagem de erro pro usuário e paro meu script.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você consegue postar o retorno do seu "confere.php"?

Porque o ajax espera que o retorno seja em formato JSON, e caso o retorno seja um JSON valido ele já faz o parse para um objeto automaticamente.

Por exemplo, eu costumo usar nas minhas aplicacoes um retorno contendo duas (ou três) propriedades:
1 - success: true ou false (para validar o processamento)
2 - data: objeto json
3 - message: caso success for false, o campo message retorna uma mensagem personalizada sobre o erro de falha

Exemplificando o retorno em codigo, seria algo assim:

```js
{
  success: true,
  data: {
    nome: "Marcelo",
    sobrenome: "Tadeu"
  }
}

ou 

{
  success: false,
  message: "Usuario ou senha inválido(s)"
}
```

e na aplicação (retorno do ajax) faria algo assim:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "confere.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {cdb: cdb}
}).done(function(data){
    var retorno = data;
    
    if(retorno.success){
      $('#nome').html(retorno.data.nome);
      $('#sobrenome').html(retorno.data.sobrenome);
    }else{
      alert(retorno.message);
    };
}).fail(function(err){
    alert("Erro no request: "+err);
});
```

Se por um acaso o cabeçalho do seu retorno não vier como "application/json", vc precisa transformar o texto em objeto json:

```js
var resposta = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: O `confere.php` não tem retorno. Ele somente pega o conteúdo do cdb pelo POST e salva em um txt.

Comment: Entendi, então neste vc faz:

if(data == 'X'){
  faz isso
}else if(data == 'Y'){
  faz aquilo
}else if(data == 'Z'){
 faz outra coisa
}

E  se der erro 500 o AJAX já vai rotear para o seu .fail()... Por isso a necessidade de retornar algo pra vc ter um controle maior...

Comment: No seu confere.php, depois do fclose($fp), de um  echo 'X' para poder tratar la no ajax...